# Blender show me a blank window in the render window?

Tags: rendering, image

I would like to render my model as image, but when I click on render image, blender only shows me a blank window, I just tested Eevee and Cycles, but there is unfortunately no difference. When I click now on render, Blender gives me only black images.

Would be awesome, if someone could help me!

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: I think you don't have a camera in your scene!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up